# Postrgresql - No Relations Found

Tags: postgresql

I'm still new to psql and I've stumbled upon a problem.

I have a user **admin** which I've granted all privileges on database **mywebsite**

```
                                   List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 mywebsite | postgres | UTF8     | en_PH.UTF-8 | en_PH.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
             |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
             |          |          |             |             | admin=CTc/postgres
 postgres    | postgres | UTF8     | en_PH.UTF-8 | en_PH.UTF-8 | 
 template0   | postgres | UTF8     | en_PH.UTF-8 | en_PH.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
             |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1   | postgres | UTF8     | en_PH.UTF-8 | en_PH.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
             |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

Here's the list of roles

```
mywebsite=# \du
 admin      |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

mywebsite=# \dn+
 public | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
        |          | =UC/postgres         | 

mywebsite=# \d
No relations found.|
```

I tried to check if the database is empty

```
mywebsite=# select count(*)
mywebsite-# from pg_class c
mywebsite-# join pg_namespace s on s.oid = c.relnamespace
mywebsite-# where s.nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
mywebsite-# and s.nspname not like 'pg_temp%'
mywebsite-# ;

 count 
-------
    36
(1 row)
```

This counts the number of tables that are not **default** Postgres tables.

So I don't know why it outputs "No Relations found"

Answer (score 0):

> This counts the number of tables that are not default Postgres tables.

Pretty sure it does not. You forgot about TOAST tables. I'm getting 40 on my somewhat fresh install of 10.1.

But this should count number of tables, sequences and a few other relations:

```
select count(*)
from pg_class c
join pg_namespace s on s.oid = c.relnamespace
where s.nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema', 'pg_toast')
and s.nspname not like 'pg_temp%'
```